# Modal Opens in Dev but not on Heroku

Tags: javascript, vue.js, heroku

I have a modal window in my front-end vue.js application, which opens in my development environment upon clicking the "Start" button, but not once deployed on Heroku. The code relevant to the modal is found below. Why is it not working on Heroku? Am I missing something?

HTML Code:

```
 <div id="login-btn" v-else>
   <button v-on:click="openModal()">Start</button>
   <AccCreation v-if="showModal" :wal="wal" :account="account" v-on:closeMod="onChildClick()" v-on:userUpdated="nameUpdated($event)"></AccCreation>
 </div>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
 openModal () {
  this.showModal = true
 }
```

Comment: What errors appear in the browser console?

Comment: Thank you @Chris Nothing. That is the main problem. The Modal just doesn't open, without generating any error.

Comment: Have you tried using the Vue.js browser extension? It's pretty hard to help without more information.

Comment: `npm install` or `yarn install` on Heroku? The browser extension generally doesn't work remotely if set up correctly

Comment: Thank you. I will try this. Yes understood that it is hard with the limited amount of info, but I thought that perhaps someone might see something obvious.

Comment: No, running those commands on Heroku won't help. All dependencies need to be declared in your `package.json` and `package-lock.json` or `yarn.lock`. Heroku automatically installs dependencies from these files during the build; running those commands interactively will install them in a one-off dyno that is discarded immediately after the command completes.